# Flexpaper does not scroll

Tags: flash, pdf

The Flexpaper flash pdf viewer (http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/) is a great idea. But the fact is I can't get mouse wheel scrolling to work for even their own example. Is there a particular setting I'm missing?

I've seen the issue with wmode at "http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/issues/detail?id=119&can=1&q=scrolling" but that doesn't seem to be what I'm facing.

No mousewheel scrolling is a real deakbreaker.

Comment: Hiya, just tried http://bit.ly/93RHGt from the examples page on the flexpaper main page and mouse wheel scrolling worked fine for me, are you using a Mac by chance because I know there's a lack of mouse wheel support in flash in general on Mac, there's a few work-arounds out there to pick up the mouse in javascript and use ExternalInterface to dispatch an event in Flex. http://blog.pixelbreaker.com/flash/swfmacmousewheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nuts. Turns out the Microsoft Mouse I'm using (http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-BlueTrack-Technology-Recharging-5AA-00001/dp/B001F7AP1Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1295301492&sr=8-1) doesn't work with the scroll. The mousewheel is one of those smooth (non-notched) types and it seems to fail with flexpaper. I tried things with a different mouse and it didn't have the same problem.

Very interesting!